# Web API POST data is null.... sometimes

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi I built that sends emails. I also have a console application that runs everynight, generates a basic report, and emails it to me, through the API.

It was working perfect, until randomly one day I stopped getting the emails. (I say randomly, but I'm sure there was something that happened, - that's why I'm here.) If I send a short HtmlMessage, like `<h1>Hi!</h1>` it works, but the longer email it actually generates hits the server as null. I'm not sure if I made a change or something that broke this, but I definitely didn't change anything in the email's html.

I have a Mailer class:

```
public class Mailer
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string HtmlMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my WebAPI:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/sendmail")]
public void Sendmail(Mailer mailer) //public void Sendmail([FromBody] Mailer mailer) tried with and without [FromBody] and neither work
{
  /* A bunch of code that doesn't matter */
}
```

And here is the code that calls the API:

```
static void Main() {
    string message;
    /* a bunch of stuff that generates the message */
    SendEmail(message);
}

static void SendEmail(string message) {
    var data = new Mailer { From = "foo@foo.com", To = "timothy@foo.com", Subject = "Daily Report", HtmlMessage = message };
    var data2 = new Mailer { From = "foo@foo.com", To = "timothy@foo.com", Subject = "Daily Report", HtmlMessage = "<h1 style=\"color: red;\">HI</h1>" };

    // I was using new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data); but changed to JSON.net as an attempt to fix
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);  // THIS DOES NOT WORK?! mailer in Sendmail is null.
    //var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2); // THIS WORKS?!

    var url = "https://server.com/api/sendmail";
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add(_headers);
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        client.UploadString(url, json);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Amy this is C# console application to WebAPI, so that won't work. I'll download Fiddler and see if I view it, but I don't think that will matter, since I've verified that the serializing works, and the overall application works with the basic message (<h2>Hey!</h2>).

Comment: So serialize takes an object and pushes to string.  I wonder if it's failing because your "message" object isn't correctly building out the string escapes?  When you hardcode it, it's fine, but maybe that message object isn't escaping quotes n' stuff properly.

Comment: @dvsoukup I figured it out. Something small and terribly stupid. Typing up answer now :)

Comment: It's always the small, syntactical issues that cause the greatest headache :)  95% of your time finding the problem, 5% of your time fixing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb, but I was able to figure it out. I have a disclaimer at the bottom of the email, where I originally had (C) but replaced it with a copyright sign (©). That appears to have broken it. I replaced it with `&copy;` and it works perfect now.

So, the issue was this character, that I assume WebAPI declined or was unable to deserialize into the Mailer class.

Anyways, it's fixed! Hopefully this helps someone else out down the road!